# GitLab Runner on VM with internal network only

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a GitLab instance from the official `jetstack` helm chart on my GKE cluster within the Google Cloud.

I would like to add a Windows VM to my VPC network that has only internal network access.

Normally you have to register the GitLab runner against the https address of GitLab which is not possible with an internal network. Is there a way to register the GitLab runner against the GitLab instance via the internal network?

The GitLab instance has its https resource published via an `nginx-ingress` controller which is running on the that GKE cluster as well.

Is there a way to register against the gitlab-unicorn pod with its internal IP that is listening on port `8080`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- `clone_url` if runner has an access to `Gitlab` instance but it's name distinct from resolved name
- `ssh-tunnel` if runner doesn't have direct access to `Gitlab` instance

## `clone_url`

If your `gitlab` is accessible from the internal network, you can use `clone_url` option

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#how-clone_url-works):

> #### How `clone_url` works
>
> In cases where the GitLab instance is exposed to an URL which can’t be used by the runner, a `clone_url` can be configured. For example; GitLab is exposed to `https://gitlab.example.com`, but the runner can’t reach that because of a firewall setup. If the runner can reach the node on `192.168.1.23`, the `clone_url` should be set to `"http://192.168.1.23`.
>
> Only if the `clone_url` is set, the runner will construct a clone URL in the form of `http://gitlab-ci-token:s3cr3tt0k3n@192.168.1.23/namespace/project.git`

## `ssh-tunnel`

If your Gitlab instance does not have any available addresses, you might setup `ssh-tunnel` to it.

> [SSH Tunneling](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling) is a method of transporting arbitrary networking data over an encrypted SSH connection. It can be used to add encryption to legacy applications. It can also be used to implement VPNs (Virtual Private Networks) and access intranet services across firewalls.

```sh
ssh -L 8080:gitlab.yourinstance.com:80 gw.yourgateway.com
```

And then you can use `gw.yourgateway.com:8080` as yours `clone_url`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but yeah clone_url helped me! I also used an internal loadbalancer within GKE combined with a seperate Nginx-Ingress.